# Cross-lagged Model with nominal repeated measures

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling

I have repeated measures of a continuous variable and a nominal variable (with 3 categories) measured across 4 time points. Does any one know any software program package that can be used to run a cross-lagged model with this type of data structure?

Comment: I would use a Markov chain, not a cross lagged model for this. See: https://www.statmodel.com/download/Dkaplan.MarkovModels.pdf